# Ajax: Undefined value for ajax success

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax

[image][image]my ajax result was working perfect but now its stuck on some queries.I am scraping data from youtube with youtube videoID given. But it not showing anything.
Like my url is  http://localhost:8080/search/6uymnYvAUKM then it will show undefined result but when I search using some keywords it works perfect.Basically I am scraping result from youtube.Its a youtube video Id. And when I search for other words it works.

```
function search_Q() {
    //alert("base url");
    var query_search = '{{Query}}';
    //alert(query_search);
    var q = query_search;//$("#q").val();
    alert(q);
    if (q) {
      $.ajax({

        url: "/api/search",
        data: { q: q },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
          $("#loading_img").css('display', 'inline');
          $("#result").empty();
        },
        success: function (result1) {
          var event_data = '';
          var title;

          //alert(check);
          for (var i = 0; i <= 14; i++) {
            if (typeof result1[i]['video']['id'] != 'undefined') {
              event_data += '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">';
              event_data += '<div class="thumbnail">';
              event_data += '<a class="item-thumbnail" style="position: relative"  target="_blank" href='+base_url+'download/' + result1[i]['video']['title_url'] + '/' + result1[i]['video']['id'] + '>';
              event_data += '<img class="ythumbnail" ' + 'src=' + result1[i]['video']['thumbnail_src'] + '> </a>';
              event_data += '<div class="search-info">';
              event_data += '<a  target="_blank" href='+base_url +'download/' +result1[i]['video']['title_url'] + '/' + result1[i]['video']['id'] + '>' + result1[i]['video']['title'] + ' </a>';
              event_data += '<p> <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" target="_blank"  href='+base_url +'download/' + result1[i]['video']['title_url'] + '/' + result1[i]['video']['id'] + '>';
              event_data += '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></i>&nbsp; Download video</a> </p> <br> </div></div></div>';
            }
          }
          $("#loading_img").css('display', 'none');
          $("#result").append(event_data);


        },
        error: function (jqxhr, status, exception) {
          alert('Sorry Try Again.', exception);
        },
        always: function (xhr, status) {
          alert("The request is complete!");
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

My Router code

```
router.get('/search/:query', function (req, res) {

  var q = req.params.query;


    res.render('index', {
      Query: q
    });


});
```

PS:I shall be very thankful if guys can help. Thanks.

Comment: What assistance are you expecting? We can't see your data, we don't know what your API is, we don't have anything we can use to understand which searches work and fail, etc. Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Your problem appears to be entirely unrelated to the code you have provided.

Comment: @adamwood If you console.log(result) is outside of your ajax function it will always be undefined, since is a asynchronus call, try to use deferred methods .done(), .then() or promises

Comment: @Dave Newton I have updated the question and added some code as well.I shall be very thankful if you can solve my problem. Btw search api is working fine.It is giving result but not for these type of queries.

Comment: @KevinB  I have updated my question.

Comment: @stanchacon my result is inside the function , its basically ajax success as you can see in the result.

Comment: @adamwood in your route, you don't appear to be doing anything when an error occurs, that would cause an unexpected response if an unexpected error occurs, but no error message would ever be presented.

Comment: @KevinB it is working perfect for all the queries when I try to search with VideoID it shows me this error. However I have tested search api with console.log ,it is giving desired result.

Comment: For me, your selector `".yt-lockup-dismissable"` returns zero results regardless of whether i use a vidid or a search term

Comment: its is working correct on my side. Its giving me all the result for vidid and search terms :( but stuck on vidid when is call from url.

Comment: Lets lay down some.... facts. If your api is returning data, jquery's success callback, if it is called, will have that data. If you are getting undefined, it is impossible that the api isn't returning undefined, assuming you don't have some kind of transformation installed into jquery that is altering the response after jQuery parses it (highly unlikely, as this is very rarely ever done.) The only other alternative at that point is it isn't undefined, and you're just logging the wrong thing. jquery by default isn't converting your json response into undefined, that's not a thing.

Comment: I have added my route code and SS of my search api result.You can check.But when I search for vidid it stucks.

Comment: typing console.log(result) into the console and expecting it to contain the ajax result is absurd. Bsides, the param name is `result1`, and the error doesn't say `result1` is undefined.

Comment: Your loop is hardcoded to loop 14 times. When you search for a video by id, you will by definition get the ***one*** video that the id references, therefore when your loop gets to the second iteration, it will fail.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH @KevinB :D That was the problem. I am feeling so silly now .Please answer it below so that I can mark it correct. Thank you so much :D

Comment: @adamwood Nosyara's answer is pretty close, just remove the first condition `result1 &&`. That will allow it to just silently skip if there is no `result1[i]`

Comment: OKAY. But you are a life saviour , Thank you @KevinB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you search by search term, you get anywhere from 1 to n results, however, when you search for a video by video id, you will always get either 1 or 0 results. Your for loop in the success callback loops 15 times, so if there are ever less than 15 results, it will fail once it processes the number of results returned and goes on to the first undefined result.

To fix this, either modify your looping so that it won't loop more times than there are results, or alter the condition inside the loop such that it doesn't check `result1[i]['video']` if `result1[i]` is undefined.

If your goal is to output *up to* 15 results, I would just modify the loop conditional such that it will stop at 15 or `result1.length`, whichever is smaller.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= Math.min(14, result1.length-1); i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Most chances the error is because you are not checking result1.
Replace line:

```
if (typeof result1[i]['video']['id'] != 'undefined') {
```

with

```
if (result1 && result1[i] && result1[i]['video'] && typeof result1[i]['video']['id'] != 'undefined') {
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but no success, its still the same. :(